# Facebook Applinks return no applink data at all

Tags: facebook, applinks

I'm using the Facebook Graph API, Mobile hosting API to post a link with the following:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{APPID}/app_link_hosts?access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}&name=Puzzle_1420352145684&ios=[{"url":"MyAPP://playerPuzzles/1420352145684","app_store_id":{MYAPPID},"app_name":"MyAPP"}]&web={"should_fallback":false}
```

I get the correct result in the form of the ID of the link, with no error.

But when I query the link with

```
https://graph.facebook.com?ids={LINK}&access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN};
```

I don't get any app-link data the object is there but empty not even the name.

```
{"http://fb.me/777314042342441" = {
        id = "http://fb.me/777314042342441";
    };
}
```

Is there something wrong in my posting that doesn't allow the data to get posted? 
Thanks for you help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the facebook documenatation is wrong. I finally found a solution using the graph explorer.
To correctly fetch the data use this style of URL.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{APP-LINK-ID}?fields=ios,name,web&access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN};
```

Please note that you have to call out all the fields you want. The object at least for me didn't include the app_links structure like the documentation.

Here is the link to the wrong [Index API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/index-api/v2.2)

Here is the [app_links object structure](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/app-link-host) you can see all the fields you can fetch.

Hope this helps everyone.

Comment: You can still use https://graph.facebook.com?ids={LINK}&access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN} you just need to also add &fields=app_links

Comment: That's what I first tried but it didn't work for me.

Comment: It depends on what version of the graph API you're using. For 2.1 and onward, it should be fields=app_links, before that, it was type=al&fields=android,ios (very unfortunate that there was a change, and I apologize for that, but it is documented in the Index API page you linked to).